# How can I have a button in one component that renders another separate component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick, components

I am trying to create an 'edit' button inside of component with an onClick that renders a separate component that is a 'client edit modal'. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

Component with the 'edit' button

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table, Container, Button } from "reactstrap";
import {
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  getClients,
  addClient,
  editClient,
  deleteClient,
} from "../actions/clientActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
class ClientTable extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getClients();
  }

  renderClient = (clients, _id) => {
    return (
      <tr key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
        <td>
          <Button
            className="remove-btn"
            color="danger"
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => this.onDeleteClick(clients._id)}
          >
            &times;
          </Button>

          <Button
            style={{ marginLeft: ".3rem" }}
            className="add-btn"
            outline
            color="warning"
            size="sm"
          >
            Edit
          </Button>

          <Button
            style={{ marginLeft: ".3rem" }}
            className="detail-btn"
            outline
            color="info"
            size="sm"
          >
            Details
          </Button>
        </td>
        <td>{clients.name}</td>
        <td>{clients.email}</td>
        <td>{clients.number}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  };

  onDeleteClick = (id) => {
    this.props.deleteClient(id);
  };

  render() {
    const { clients } = this.props.client;
    return (
      <Container id="listContainer">
        <Table
          id="listTable"
          className="table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
          dark
        >
          <tr class="listRow">
            <thead id="tableHeader">
              <tr>
                <th id="listActions">Actions</th>
                <th id="listName">Name</th>
                <th id="listEmail">Email</th>
                <th id="listNumber">Number</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="listRow">{clients.map(this.renderClient)}</tbody>
          </tr>
        </Table>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

ClientTable.propTypes = {
  getClients: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  client: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  client: state.client,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getClients,
  deleteClient,
  addClient,
})(ClientTable);
```

Component that button will render

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { editClient } from "../actions/clientActions";
import { CLIENTS_LOADING } from "../actions/types";

class ClientEditModal extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    name: "",
    email: "",
    number: "",
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal,
    });
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const editClient = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      number: this.state.number,
    };

    this.props.editClient(editClient);

    this.toggle();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}> Edit Client</ModalHeader>

          <ModalBody>
            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="name"> Name </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  id="client"
                  placeholder="Add name"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                ></Input>
                <Label for="email"> Email </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="email"
                  id="client"
                  placeholder="Add email"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                ></Input>
                <Label for="number"> Number </Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="number"
                  id="client"
                  placeholder="Add number"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                ></Input>
                <Button color="dark" style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }} block>
                  Submit Changes
                </Button>
              </FormGroup>
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  client: state.client,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { editClient })(ClientEditModal);
```

I also would like to do the same for the 'details' button, but I assume that would be rather simple once I figure out how to do it once. If anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful! Thank you

Comment: you can store the modal property in the ClientTable state and just pass it to ClientEditModal

Comment: How do I pass it to the ClientEditModal?

Comment: state = {
    modal: false,
  };

Comment: onClick={this.state.modal}

Comment: use the ClientEditModal component in the rendering method of the ClientTable component. In the ClientTable state, add the isOpen property, set it to false and switch it using the edit button. Pass this property to ClientEditModal and use it instead of the modal property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
class ClientEditModal extends Component {
//...
componentDidMount() {
   if (this.props.isOpen) {
     this.toggle(true);
   }
}

toggle = (isOpen) => {
    this.setState({
      modal: isOpen,
    });
}

// ...
}
```

and in your `ClientTable`, create a new state `isOpen` that you flip when you press the edit button.

```js
showModal = () => {
   this.setState({ isOpen: true; });
}

//...

<Button onClick={this.showModal}>Edit</Button>
```

Then pass the `isOpen` state to the `ClientEditModal`

```js
<ClientEditModal isOpen={this.state.isOpen} {...otherProps} />
```

Comment: How do I get access to the ClientEditModal state within the ClientTable?

Comment: At which point you want to access the ClientEditModal state? When the user exits the modal for example?

Comment: I'd like to access the state when they click the 'edit' button on the ClientTable.

Comment: It doesn't seem logical to me to try to access the ClientEditModal state when the user clicks the Edit button, because by then, the ClientEditModal state is supposed to be empty